# Solving trigonometric equation $\sin x+1=\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin x+1=\cos x, x\in[-\pi,\pi]$

Hi I'm confused about a trig question. The question asks to solve using a half angle identity and in the solution it states to subtract 2π from 3π/2 resulting in one of the solutions being -π/2 along with another solution of zero.  After using the half angle identity I got -1=tanx/2 and from there in Q2 I found x to be 3π/2 and in Q4 I found x to be 7π/2. Neither of these are in the domain so the solution says to subtract 2π from 3π/2. Would the period be 2π since it is a half angle identity, I'm confused how you know the period is 2π since it is tan?
Thanks

Comment: Check Dr. Graubner's answer on [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1577393/7163).

Answer (score 0):

$(\sin x+1=\cos x)$ iff $(1-\cos x=-\sin x)$ iff $(2\sin^2(x/2)=\sin x=-2\sin (x/2) \cos (x/2))$ iff $(\sin (x/2)=0$ or $0\ne \sin (x/2)=-\cos (x/2)).$ Now  $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$ iff $x/2\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ so (1)...$\sin (x/2)=0$ iff $x/2=0$ iff $x=0$, while (2)... $(0\ne \sin (x/2)=-\cos (x/2))$ iff $ x/2=\pi/4$ iff $x=\pi/2.$